# Using collectingAndThen() with Collectors.toMap() requires explicit type cast

Tags: java, java-8, guava

I have a `Map<String,BigDecimal>` (say amountMap) which I want to convert to an `ImmutableMap<String,Double>`, code for which is:

```
return amountMap.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(collectingAndThen(toMap(e->e.getKey(),e->e.getValue().doubleValue()),ImmutableMap::copyOf));
```

However Eclipse shows an error which says that e.getKey() and e.getValue() require explicit type casting since they are of type Object.

The same code works when I split it like so:

```
Map<String,Double> tempMap = amountMap.entrySet().stream()
                                .collect(toMap(e->e.getKey(),e->e.getValue().doubleValue());

return ImmutableMap.copyOf(tempMap);
```

I am assuming the former error is because of Type Erasure, but if not, is there a way to return the Map as an ImmutableMap without the intermediate step of creating a temporary map to hold the results ?

Comment: Have you tried with javac? Eclipse uses its own compiler (which version of Eclipse do you use?). I don't know if ECJ has still type inference problems where javac is able to infer the types but it was the case in the past.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour with Eclipse Mars.1 or javac 1.8.0.51. How are you compiling?

Comment: It's a little bit off-topic, but the conversion can be done using guava: `Map<String,Double> tempMap = Maps.transformValues(amountMap, BigDecimal::doubleValue)` (I haven't tried compiling it, but you get the idea)

Comment: As you all deduced, this was due to using an old version of Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because I was using an old version of Eclipse(Luna) was fixed on upgrading